Project Reactor Mono.just inside a flatMap
trying to search some information regarding the usage of this but not yet found a definitive answer to this. the usage of flatMap on blocking operations (non reactive). when some operations like outboundCalls is reactive, we can use a flatMap right away to make it async and non blocking.
  .flatMap(data -> outboundCall(data))

But the issue came when the outboundCall is a non reactive one.
  .map(data -> outboundCall(dbData))

vs
  .flatMap(data -> Mono.just(outboundCall(data)))

Is there really any gain on wrapping with Mono.just inside a flatMap? or is it just gonna create some overhead?

In a reactive context, if you have a blocking operation to perform, you should ideally offload that work onto a separate thread to not block the main reactive stream. You could use Mono.fromCallable() together with .subscribeOn() to move the blocking call to a different thread like this:
.flatMap(data -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> outboundCall(data))
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))

Such an approach utilizes the Schedulers.boundedElastic() scheduler which is meant for slow, blocking tasks. It avoids blocking the main reactive flow and applies backpressure as needed.

oh i see, so to make it non blocking need to wrap it with that approach. just to clarify more things, since we need to bundle the outboundCall like that, the flatMap with Mono.just will just the same with .map only and just block the main stream right?
